# Pass data between cordova plugin to angular

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, angular7

I've working on Angular/Cordova app and want pass online/offline  status to angular:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isOff = false;
  constructor() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
      document.addEventListener('offline', onOffline, false);
      document.addEventListener('online', onOnline, false);
      function onOffline() {
        alert('You are offline.');//Working
        this.isOff = true;//Not working
      }
      function onOnline() {
        alert('You are Online.'); //Working
        this.isOff = false; //Not working
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow functions in constructor:

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => this.onDeviceReady(), false);
    document.addEventListener('pause', () => this.onPause(), false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', () => this.onResume(), false);
    document.addEventListener('offline', () => this.onOffline(), false);
    document.addEventListener('online', () => this.onOnline(), false);
```

Now you can use your Angular variable.

```
onDeviceReady() {
    console.log('---onDeviceReady--->');
}

onPause() {
    console.log('---onPause--->');
}

onResume() {
    console.log('---onResume--->');
}

onOffline() {
    console.log('---onOffline--->');
    this.isOff = true;
}

onOnline() {
    console.log('---onOnline--->');
    this.isOff = false;
}
```